# WorkAround for XD-2772: No validation for module packaging during module upload

Tags: spring-xd

I created a custom module and registered it as mentioned in Spring-XD doc.
During stream deployment, I am getting similar error:

```
 Mar 02, 2015 10:45:48 PM org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy invoke

 SEVERE: Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Multiple top level module resources found :file [/opt/spring-xd/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/jms-activemq.properties],file [/opt/spring-xd/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/xd-container-logger.properties],file [/opt/spring-xd/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/jms-hornetq.properties],file [/opt/spring-xd/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/xd-singlenode-logger.properties],file [/opt/spring-xd/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/xd-admin-logger.properties],file [/opt/spring-xd/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/httpSSL.properties],file [/opt/spring-xd/spring-xd-1.1.0.RELEASE/xd/config/hadoop.properties]
```

I understand that my module lacks, config file and properties file.

So, I want to understand, can I copy files manually?
If yes, then what will be the location

Thanks in advance.

Resolution:

```
    1. Create "config" directory at $XD_HOME/modules/processor/<name>/
    2. Add <name>.xml to $XD_HOME/modules/processor/<name>/config
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is misleading (this has been fixed on current master at the time of writing).

Indeed, your module certainly lacks its `config/xxx.properties` file. If you use one of the dedicated build plugins (either maven or gradle), this should help you packaging your module properly. Those plugins expect that file to be at `src/main/resources/config/foo.properties` in source form (which will end up as `your.jar!/config/foo.properties` in built form)